# Is it useful to set an INDEX on an AUTO_INCREMENT column?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, binary-search

An `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` is already in numerical order, so queries, at least in my basic understanding of databases, would implement a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) from the start, so what use is there in setting an index on such a column? I understand the use if the integers are in a semi-random order, but I do not see the point on an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Comment: Usefull? MySQL forces you to add a key (INDEX) on a AUTO_INCREMENT option.. You get the error "Error: ER_WRONG_AUTO_KEY: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key" if you don't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to create another index for a PRIMARY KEY.

In InnoDB, the PRIMARY KEY is also called the **clustered index**. This means the whole table itself is stored as a B-tree, sorted by the column(s) defined for the table's primary key.

This actually has nothing to do with the fact that the AUTO_INCREMENT column stores increasing numbers. Even if you don't use AUTO_INCREMENT, and you insert rows in random order, they will be inserted into the clustered index in ascending order.

Comment: Also it's very important to always create your own primary / unique key when using InnoDB engine...Post off mine https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by/48184#48184 explaining why

Comment: @RaymondNijland, sure that's a good practice, but I assume the OP already has defined a primary key. They are asking if they need to define an index on the same columns in addition to the existing primary key.